# Changing the Missing Value

Tags: r

how can i finished this?

> Create an "R Function" where the function can be used to replace the missing value of a vector with the mean value of the vector.

Vector with missing value (input):

```
df <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,NA,7,8,9,NA)
df
mean_replace <- ...

df <- mean_replace(df) df
```

The vector after the missing value is replaced with the mean (output):

```
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 5 7 8 9 5
```

My Answer:

```
df <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,NA,7,8,9,NA)
df
mean_replace <- is.na(df)
df <- mean_replace(df)
df
```

but still failed :

```
> df <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,NA,7,8,9,NA)

> df
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6 NA  7  8  9 NA

> mean_replace <- df(mean)
```

> argument "df1" is missing, with no default

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replace` -

```
df <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,NA,7,8,9,NA)
mean_replace <- function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), mean(x, na.rm = TRUE))

df <- mean_replace(df)
df
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 5 7 8 9 5
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to assign the mean, with `NA` values removed from the input (using `na.rm=TRUE`), to any `NA` slots in the input vector:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,NA,7,8,9,NA)
x[is.na(x)] <- mean(x, na.rm=TRUE)
x

[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 5 7 8 9 5
```